# Variable not found in makefile recipe

Tags: gnu-make

why doesn't this simple recipe work ?

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    foo := $(shell ls | grep makefile) ;\
    echo $(foo)
```

results in

```
$> make test
makefile:65: warning: undefined variable 'foo'
foo := makefile ;\
echo 
/bin/sh: 1: foo: not found
```

So, as far as I understand, the variable `foo` is well set to value `makefile` but it cannot be used afterwards ? However, it is a single line command, executed in the same shell ?

However, this works

```
@$(eval export foo := $(shell ls | grep makefile)) \
echo $(foo)
```

So I guess that the variable in the first example is not accessible because the assignment is not evaluated yet at the time we try the `echo` ?

And if I dig a little further, how to do this work

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @$(eval export files = $(shell ls))
    for f in $(files) ; do \
        t = $(ls | grep $$f) ; \
        echo $$t;\
    done
```

Comment: The term `receipe` is not a common practice together with `make`. Are you talking about a `command` from a **rule**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your loop...  quoted here:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @$(eval export files = $(shell ls))
    for f in $(files) ; do \
        t = $(ls | grep $$f) ; \
        echo $$t;\
    done
```

So... `$(eval ... )` runs a command in make.

`$(shell ls)` runs command `ls` in the shell, and substitutes its output.

The command run by the `$(eval ... )` is thus something like `export files = file file2 makefile source.c`.  This command makes a make variable called files and exports it to child makes.  Thus, the export probably isn't needed.

The entire `$(eval ... )` could probably be replaced with `files = $(wildcard *)`  And it could probably use `:=` and be placed outside of a rule.

The `for` loop, four lines, is run in the shell.  The first thing that is done, the make variables and functions are substituted.  The one that is weird is `$(ls | grep $$f)`.  Since ls is not a make function, this will try   to expand a variable, which isn't defined.  This is an empty string.  If this was meant to be the shell's `$(...)` operator, you need to double the $.  `$$` is expanded to `$`.  `$(files)` is expanded based on the eval.

This becomes (using my previous example):

```
for f in file file2 makefile source.c ; do
    t =
    echo $t;
done
```

At first glance, this might echo four blank lines, but no.  The command `t =` actually runs the program `t` and passes the equal sign as an argument.  `t` probably doesn't exist.  Thus, we get four errors that t isn't a valid program, each followed by a blank line (unless t is elsewhere defined).

Something closer to what you wanted might be:

```
files := $(wildcard *)
.PHONY: test
test:
    for f in $(files) ; do \
        t=$$(ls | grep $$f) ; \
        echo $$t ; \
    done
```

This will output:

```
file file2
file2
makefile
source.c
```

Note that the first line listed two files, as the both include "file" in the name.  If that isn't what you want, you might consider:

```
files := $(wildcard *)
.PHONY: test
test:
    for f in $(files) ; do \
        echo $$f ; \
    done
```

or even (may be GNU make specific):

```
files := $(wildcard *)
.PHONY: test
test:
    $(foreach f, $(files), echo $f ; )
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for the very pedagogic answer. It is my very first try with makefiles and I'm trying to understand them. You surely helped me !

Comment: The solution you propose is one I tried, however, I got errors like : "/bin/sh: 2: t: not found" for each file

Comment: `/bin sh: 2: t: not found` is a result of trying to execute the command `t`.  In make, assignment is <variable> <whitespace> = <whitespace> <value>.  in sh, assignment does NOT allow whitespace.  <variable>=<value>   In fact in sh, you can write: `A=1 B=2 myprogram` and it will set two the variable for the execution of a program, but not retain them beyond that.  There is also a shell option that will allow you to write it as `myprogram A=1 B=2` -- but I've never heard of anyone seriously using that option.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a make target recipe, commands are processed differently (by spawning a shell) than logic outside a recipe.

You can either move the variable outside the recipe:

```
.PHONY: test
foo := $(shell ls | grep makefile)
test:
    echo $(foo)
```

or,  courtesy of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/790560/variables-in-gnu-make-recipes-is-that-possible), use an eval:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    $(eval foo=$(shell ls | grep makefile))
    echo $(foo)
```

Both output the below:

```
echo makefile
makefile
```

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're trying with your for loop. It looks like you are trying to run `ls` in a very roundabout way. Also, beware consuming the output of `ls`.